# pipes `take` with default value

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I have a producer `p` with type `Producer Message IO (Producer SB.ByteString IO ())`.
Now I need optionally skip some messages and optionally process certain number of messages:

```
       let p =
             (processMBFile f >->
              P.drop (optSkip opts)
              >->
              (case optLimit opts of
                 Nothing -> cat
                 Just n  -> ptake n)
             )
       in
         do
           restp <- runEffect $ for p processMessage
```

I could not use `take` from Pipes.Prelude because it returns `()` while I need to return an empty producer. The way I quickly haked it is by replacing `take` with my own implementation `ptake`:

```
emptyP :: Producer SB.ByteString IO ()
emptyP = return ()

ptake :: Monad m => Int -> Pipe a a m (Producer SB.ByteString IO ())
ptake = go
  where
    go 0 = return emptyP
    go n = do
        a <- await
        yield a
        go (n-1)
```

My question is: if there is a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: If I'm not overlooking anything, since you are always returning `emptyP`, your `ptake` can be written as `ptake n = emptyP <$ take n`

Comment: I am also surprised there is no generic version of `emptyP` in the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ptake` differs from `take` only in the return value, so it can be implemented in terms of it using `(<$)`:

```
ptake n = emptyP <$ take n
```